# Can a private channel communication happen between two Pusher Apps

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, pusher

I have two iOS apps, lets call it Agent app and Customer App. 
I have a chat feature between these two apps, but the chats need to be recorded on the server.

I have created two Pusher Apps, one for each of the iOS apps. They both subscribe to their respective `private-{id}-channel`.

Now every time a message is generated from say Agent app (via HTTP request to server), I want server to create a pusher event with Agent's message on Customer's private channel.

Is it possible to achieve the above using Pusher Private channels?

Comment: Just make them both join the same channel

Comment: @Rao Have got any solution? Do you have any other idea how basically this is done, any suggestion or tutorial will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could achieve this is by having both users join the same channel.

Let's say you have two users: `user-a` and `user-b`. **Both** users subscribe to a common private channel `private-chat-user-a-user-b`.

```
let myChannel = pusher.subscribe("private-chat-user-a-user-b")
```

Then triggering client events on the channel

```
myChannel.trigger(eventName: "client-my-event", data: ["your": "data"])
```

[Client events](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#trigger-events) are a way of sending messages just between clients, without a server relaying them.

Disclosure: I work at pusher.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to record the chat on server, therefore, instead of making Customer App directly sending message on Agent App channel, I made the Customer App call my server API, which records the message and relies it on channel that Agent App is listening to.